# Tasks done by ssh server when it receives a request?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sshd

When I ssh into a server using

```
ssh -vvv user@ip
```

It gives me all the information of the steps that a particular `client` is performing in order to connect to a OpenSSH Server.

I was Wondering if there is a way to know all the similar steps that a `server` (sshd daemon) will perform when it is requested by a `client` to make a connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to do this temporarily (to debug a particular problem, for example), you can run `sshd` interactively with the debug flag set.

1. Log into the server and become root.
2. Halt the regular SSH daemon.
3. Run sshd interactively with the debug flag set:

   /usr/sbin/sshd -d
4. Run the client and do the test that you're trying to troubleshoot.

`sshd` will run in the foreground within your terminal and output debugging information.

If you don't want to halt the normal ssh server, you can run your debug server on a different port:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 10022
```

Then have your client connect to the alternate port.

Comment: You could also stop the running ssh daemon (service sshd stop) and run the debug sshd on port 22. Stopping ssh will not disconnect your existing sessions. Be sure to restart ssh before closing the existing sessions.

Comment: @mtak hence step 2: "Halt the regular SSH daemon."

Comment: My bad, wasn't paying attention :)

Comment: Thnxx This was precisely what i looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Modify the log file (generally [/etc/sshd/config](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config+5)) for the sshd to have the most verbose logging possible.  Specifics may vary, but DEBUG3 is likely the highest .  As the man page states:

```
 LogLevel
     Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages from
     sshd.  The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO, VER-
     BOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2 and DEBUG3.  The default is INFO.
     DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent.  DEBUG2 and DEBUG3 each specify
     higher levels of debugging output.  Logging with a DEBUG level
     violates the privacy of users and is not recommended.
```